# Return rows for customers only where values in a certain column are either x or y

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of customer emails, and the status of their account at different dates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email': pd.Series(['john@email.com', 'john@email.com', 'mary@email.com', 'mary@email.com', 'patrick@email.com', 'patrick@email.com', 'foo@email.com', 'foo@email.com'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)), 'date_created': pd.Series(['18/04/2018', '19/04/2018', '18/04/2018', '18/05/2018', '12/05/2019', '15/05/2019', '12/08/2019', '15/08/2019'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)), 'status': pd.Series(['Account Open ', 'Account Closed', 'Lead', 'Account Open ', 'Account Open ', 'Account Closed', 'Lead', 'Account Open '],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1))

               email date_created          status
0     john@email.com   18/04/2018   Account Open 
1     john@email.com   19/04/2018  Account Open
2     mary@email.com   18/04/2018            Lead
3     mary@email.com   18/05/2018   Account Open 
4  patrick@email.com   12/05/2019   Account Open 
5  patrick@email.com   15/05/2019  Account Closed
6      foo@email.com   12/08/2019            Lead
7      foo@email.com   15/08/2019   Account Open
```

I am interested in finding the time between when they were a `Lead` to when the status changed to `Account Open`.

Therefore I only want customers who have both these two statuses, in this case `foo@email.com` and `mary@email.com` above.

How can I extract the customers who have these two statuses only? I want to disregard everybody else. So my expected outcome would be:

```
               email date_created          status
2     mary@email.com   18/04/2018            Lead
3     mary@email.com   18/05/2018   Account Open 
6      foo@email.com   12/08/2019            Lead
7      foo@email.com   15/08/2019   Account Open
```

I tried:

```
df[df['status'].str.contains('|'.join(['Lead','Account Open']),na=False)]
```

But I end up with `john@email.com` in the list because he has an `Account Open` status. He doesn't have a `Lead` record so I want to ignore him.

Any advice?

**edit** just to clarify. maybe I should have started like this.

I have a dataframe with fruit purchases.

```
   id        date      fruit
0   1  01/01/2019     apple 
1   1  02/01/2019     banana
2   2  03/01/2019     orange
3   2  04/01/2019  pineapple
4   3  05/01/2019    tomoato
5   3  06/01/2019      lemon
6   4  07/01/2019     apple 
7   4  08/01/2019     banana
8   5  09/01/2019      melon
9   5  10/01/2019     apple
```

I want to extract all the customer records who bought an apple and banana only. In this case `id 1` and `id 4`. I would like to extract their records like so:

```
   id        date      fruit
0   1  01/01/2019     apple 
1   1  02/01/2019     banana
6   4  07/01/2019     apple 
7   4  08/01/2019     banana
```

This will allow me to measure the time difference between purchases of apples and bananas.

Comment: So it works if contains both statuses?

Comment: Does `lead` has to come before `Account Open` or are you purely looking for emails who have both?

Answer (score 1):

Idea is compare first duplicate value by `Lead` and second duplicate value by `Account Open`, chain conditions by `&` for AND and `|` for `OR` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m1 = df['status'].str.contains('Lead',na=False)
m2 = df['status'].str.contains('Account Open', na=False)
```

Or test by `==`:

```
m1 = df['status'] == 'Lead'
m2 = df['status'].str.strip() == 'Account Open'
mask = df['email'].duplicated()

df = df[(~mask & m1) | (mask & m2)]
print (df)
            email date_created         status
2  mary@email.com   18/04/2018           Lead
3  mary@email.com   18/05/2018  Account Open 
6   foo@email.com   12/08/2019           Lead
7   foo@email.com   15/08/2019  Account Open
```

If possible more like 2 value of email per groups and is necessry filter only groups with 2 rows add another mask:

```
mask1 = df.groupby('email')['email'].transform('size').eq(2)

df = df[((~mask & m1) | (mask & m2) ) & mask1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check if the statuses are `Lead` and `Account Open`.

Finally we use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with `all` to check if the whole "group" is `True`:

```
df['indicator'] = df['status'].str.strip().isin(['Lead', 'Account Open'])

dfn = df[df.groupby('email')['indicator'].transform('all')]
```

```
            email date_created         status  indicator
2  mary@email.com   18/04/2018           Lead       True
3  mary@email.com   18/05/2018  Account Open        True
6   foo@email.com   12/08/2019           Lead       True
7   foo@email.com   15/08/2019  Account Open        True
```

---

**Testing solution on 2nd example dataframe**:

```
df['indicator'] = df['fruit'].isin(['apple', 'banana'])

df[df.groupby('id')['indicator'].transform('all')]
```

```
   id        date   fruit  indicator
0   1  01/01/2019   apple       True
1   1  02/01/2019  banana       True
6   4  07/01/2019   apple       True
7   4  08/01/2019  banana       True
```

Comment: _"Therefore I only want customers who have both these two statuses"_. I read the question differentely, I asked OP for clarification, let's wait for response

Comment: This is correct. I wanted mary and foo because they each have a lead status and account open status.

Comment: By the way, I am finding emails that only have one status `Lead`. I was looking for emails with both so I can measure the time between `Lead` and `Account Open`. It's difficult to explain, perhaps I didn't explain it well. Also, for your original question - no, lead does not have to come before account open. I just wanted `email` and their statuses, where statuses are only `Lead` and `Account Open`, and only emails who have both these statuses.

Comment: You mean that status goes from `Lead > Account Open > Lead`?

Comment: The order doesn't matter. I'll try and re-write and upload another question tomorrow.

Comment: Im not sure what the problem is exactly? For your second dataframe it will still work. See edit in my answer @SCool

Comment: @SCool - Difference is my answer working if order is `'Lead', 'Account Open'` only, Erfan answer working if all these combinations - `'Lead', 'Account Open'`, `'Account Open','Lead'`, `'Account Open', 'Account Open'`, `'Lead', 'Lead'`, because testing with `isin`

Answer (score 0):

Probably not pretty but works:

`df[df['email'].isin(df[df['status'] == 'Lead']['email'])]`